# Reference variable parameter vs local reference variable

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

Is there a major difference between passing a object through a function by reference vs creating a local reference variable and setting it equal to an object.

For context, state.clone() returns a std::unique_ptr to a OthelloGameState object. makeMove() is not a const function which is probably whats causing the segmentation fault when its being called on a const object.

For some reason when I create a local reference variable, set it equal to the cloned OthelloGameState, and call makeMove() I got a segmentation fault. Like I stated previous I am figuring this is because the object that is returned from state.clone() is still const which would cause a crash when I call makeMove() on it.

```
virtual std::pair<int, int> chooseMove(const OthelloGameState& state)
{
    OthelloGameState& duplicateState = *state.clone();
    duplicateState.makeMove(2,3);

    return std::make_pair(0,0);
}
```

However, what is confusing to me is that I managed to fix this by passing it through a function by reference then calling the same makeMove() function on it. The code below works perfectly and I got no segmentation fault.

```
virtual std::pair<int, int> chooseMove(const OthelloGameState& state)
{
    moveMe(*state.clone());
    return std::make_pair(0,0);
}

void moveMe(OthelloGameState& state)
{
    state.makeMove(2,3);
}
```

Is there a reason why calling makeMove() on a local reference would cause a segmentation fault, while passing it through a function first by reference then calling the same makeMove() function would work perfectly fine? I did the same experiment with pointers rather then reference and I got the same results.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: `*state.clone()` does memory leak (or if you use smart pointer, that creates dangling pointer).

Comment: If you work for a company like mine that blocks imgur using images of your code makes your question unreadable.

Comment: @NathanOliver you're not missing much

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry I didn't think of that. I typed it all out.

Comment: It is throroughly irrational to post pictures of text, or links to them. (1) It is much more work than posting the text; (2) it wastes bandwidth of readers; and (3) it prevents cut and paste for use in comments and answers. Don't do it here.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, I typically don't post images of text. In this case I did it because I was coding within a virtual machine so it was impossible for me to copy and past it, as I was writing the stack overflow post outside of the virtual machine. I manually wrote all the code again within the post so it should be fixed.

Comment: Perhaps you need a better VM - VirtualBox certainly allows you to copy and paset between host and guest windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unique_ptr` created by `state.clone()` is destroyed at **end of expression**.
So your reference/pointer is dangling.

Use instead:

```
auto cloned = state.clone();
cloned->makeMove(2, 3);
```

Comment: Alright well correct me if I'm wrong, but what I understand from what you posted is that cloned is another unique_ptr which is calling the move assignment operator / copy constructor before the unique_ptr that is returned from state.clone() goes out of scope. This is swapping the contents which means that the unique_ptr from state.clone() is not pointing to the object when it goes out of scope. However, I don't understand why passing it through a function worked. How would the function call operator= or the copy constructor when the parameter is not a unique_ptr.

Comment: @BrandonLavigne: in `moveMe(*state.clone());`, the `unique_ptr` is destroyed at end of expression, so at `;`, so after the call to `MoveMe`.